# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" React

Tags: reactjs

I am new in React , I was following the course of React. And the code as follow appeared issue like "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"; Can anyone tell what's going on ? Thank you so much!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const ListGroup = props => {
    const {items,textProperty,valueProperty} = props;
    return ( 
      <ul className="list-group">
          {items.map(item =>(
         <li key={item[valueProperty]} className="list-group-item">
             {item[textProperty]}
         </li>
          ))}
          
      </ul>
     );
}
 
export default ListGroup;
```

Comment: That means that the `items` object hasn't been set (undefined reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `items` object is undefined at the start. Just add a null check:

```
const ListGroup = props => {
    const {items,textProperty,valueProperty} = props;
    return ( 
      <ul className="list-group">
          {items && items.map(item =>(
               <li key={item[valueProperty]} className="list-group-item">
                 {item[textProperty]}
               </li>
          ))}
          
      </ul>
     );
}
```

Comment: thank you so much ,I am new on posting a question on stack overflow also ..

Comment: no problem, if this helped you make sure to accept it as the answer :) happy coding

Comment: Why did you unaccept my earlier answer, which works. You can vote up for other helpful answers, but you should accept the earliest working answer. `items && items.map` and `items?.map` do the same thing, they execute the map function if items is not *falsy*

Comment: Hi Sinan Yaman ,I am so sorry , I didn't notice I unaccepted your answers .I like your anser ,and It works for me .Thank you so much and sorry again ..

Comment: No problem,  just pointing out what is the common accepted behavior around here. No need to say sorry, you are a new contributor. You can still upvote any answer that helped you or you liked.You can take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You can upvote as many answers you would like, but you can accept only one answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion and understanding !  Now I understand what was going on ...  It won't happen more : )  Good day !

Answer (score 2):

You didn't seem to pass `items` prop to `ListGroup`:

```
<ListGroup items=[] />
```

Alternatively, you can assign a default value to items:

```
const {items = [],textProperty,valueProperty} = props;
```

Or use elvis operator:

```
items?.map(item => {})
```

Comment: Hi Pavlo ,thank you so much for your answer ,I had  passes the items in my another file as  :  <ListGroup 
                        items={this.setState.genres} 
                        textProperty ="name"
                        valueProperty ="_id"
                        onItemSelect={this.handleGenreSelect}/>; state = { 
        movies : [],
        genres :[],
        pageSize :4,
        currentPage : 1
     } ; but dosen't work ...

Comment: @YellowClock this looks off, you probably want: items={this.state.genres}

Comment: You got me Pavlo!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use operate chaining, change your code to:

````
const ListGroup = props => {
    const {items,textProperty,valueProperty} = props;
    return ( 
      <ul className="list-group">

          { items?.map(item =>(
               <li key={item[valueProperty]} className="list-group-item">
                 {item[textProperty]}
               </li>
          ))}
          
      </ul>
     );
}
```
````

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Crispen !

Comment: If you find it Helpful please vote for the answer

Comment: Hi Crispen ,I had voted , however I recieved "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I am not sure it will work ..

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking the same course. Make sure that you have passed the right props to ListGroup in Movies class just like that:

```
<ListGroup
                items={this.state.genres}
                textProperty="name"
                valueProperty="_id"
                onItemSelect={this.handleGenreSelect}
/>
```

Regards!